# Printing a groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df.groupby("female").apply(display)
```

This displays all the groups in the dataset but my dataset is very large and my VScode crashed after I ran this since the output was long, So how to display only the first n groups, just to get an idea of how my grouped data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on the nice answer from @Prayson, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get only the first few groups:

```
from itertools import islice

n = 5
top_n = list(islice(df.groupby('female'), n))
```

Comment: That is clever. As you can slice starting at any point, to a given point with jumps  `print([k for k in islice([1,2,3,4,5], 1,4,2)])`

Comment: Pretty print version of this is:
`n = 5`
`pd.DataFrame(list(islice(ratings_group, n)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator. For example if you want to call only the first group, you can call `next` on generator once.

```py
…
group_gen = (group for group in df.groupby("female"))

# get first group: returns tuple 
g = next(group_gen)

# show g
display(g[1])
```

Generators allows you to lazy load what you need.

To load N times you would call next N times

```py
gs = pd.concat((next(group_gen)[1] for _ in range(N)), ignore_index=True)

display(gs)
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, thank you. Why g[1] we already got the first group right with next

Comment: groupby returns a tuple `(group_name, group_contents)` for each group. So we access the second element [1] :)